# Parallax scrolling cross browser compatibility

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, scroll, parallax, requestanimationframe

After watching this two part tutorial on ([here's part two](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O39OEPC20GM&t=16m51s)) I've got parallax scrolling up and running. Where the clip starts he introduces cross browser compatibility using [Paul Irish's requestAnimationFrame](http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/) and that's what I can't get to work. He just pastes the code right into the code and it works but I can't get it to run in any other browser except Chrome. Although, when pasted something is happening to the images so I suppose it does something...

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? One suggestion was moving the requestAnimationFrame before the other code but that didn't change anything. I've set up a JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6LMQ6/) so please help yourself. Any pointer is helpful.

Here's my code:

```
    (function () {
        var lastTime = 0;
        var vendors = ['webkit', 'moz'];
        for (var x = 0; x < vendors.length && !window.requestAnimationFrame; ++x) {
            window.requestAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x] + 'RequestAnimationFrame'];
            window.cancelAnimationFrame =
              window[vendors[x] + 'CancelAnimationFrame'] || window[vendors[x] + 'CancelRequestAnimationFrame'];
        }

        if (!window.requestAnimationFrame)
            window.requestAnimationFrame = function (callback, element) {
                var currTime = new Date().getTime();
                var timeToCall = Math.max(0, 16 - (currTime - lastTime));
                var id = window.setTimeout(function () { callback(currTime + timeToCall); },
                  timeToCall);
                lastTime = currTime + timeToCall;
                return id;
            };

        if (!window.cancelAnimationFrame)
            window.cancelAnimationFrame = function (id) {
                clearTimeout(id);
            };
    }());

    (function ($) {

        var $container = $(".parallax");
        var $divs = $container.find("div.parallax-background");
        var thingBeingScroll = document.body;
        var liHeight = $divs.eq(0).closest("li").height();
        var diffHeight = $divs.eq(0).height() - liHeight;
        var len = $divs.length;

        var i, div, li, offset, scroll, top, transform;

        var offsets = $divs.get().map(function (div, d) {
            return $(div).offset();
        });

        var render = function () {

            top = thingBeingScroll.scrollTop;

            for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                div = $divs[i];

                offset = top - offsets[i].top;

                scroll = ~~((offset / liHeight * diffHeight) * 3);

                transform = 'translate3d(0px,' + scroll + 'px,0px)';

                div.style.webkitTransform = transform;
                div.style.MozTransform = transform;
                div.style.msTransform = transform;
                div.style.OTransform = transform;
                div.style.transform = transform;
            }
        };

        (function loop() {
            requestAnimationFrame(loop);
            render();
        })();

    })(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well apart from jQuery not getting loaded into jsFiddle properly, I think your problem was with scrollTop support. Try this **[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/49AEJ/)** which uses the jquery shim for scrollTop and the window property intead;

```
            var $thingBeingScroll = $(window);
```

and

```
            top = $thingBeingScroll.scrollTop();
```

But now it looks like you have the same problem I'm currently having. Namely, the scroll is jumpy on IE and FF compared to Chrome.

It's as if the smooth scrolling on FF and IE (which chrome doesn't have) is somehow moving the background slab on scroll before we get a chance to update it. It also issues an array of scroll changes which means that after you let go of the scroll bar, it then has to redraw the positions starting back at the begining and working its way back to current position. I believe that's what causes the jerkiness.

I believe `requestAnimationFrame` will stack up requests, so it may be that we need to cancel any previous outstanding ones if we've a more recent one and/or use higher resolution updates like `mousemove`.

Comment: Well, you solved the compatibility problem but like you say, it is jumpy. For me it's only in FF that it's smooth. I wonder why that is because it's equally smooth when you pull the slider to scroll instead of using the scroll wheel.

Comment: I'm always use the slider to test because my thinkpad trackpad is notoriously jumpy. I find Chrome the smoothest, then FF, then IE the most jumpy. I really need a solution to the lumpiness myself. I arrived here looking for an answer to that :) www.onedrive.com/about have it smooth as silk on IE11. Other than the greensock library, I can't see a huge difference in what they are doing vs what we are doing.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.

The OneDrive site is jump in IE11 for me, not in Chrome and FF. And not at all on Safari and Chrome on OS X.

Comment: I tried out this solution and it works really good once you try out some different scroll speeds. http://bassta.bg/2013/05/smooth-page-scrolling-with-tweenmax/

Comment: Yep. That's the greensock library that onedrive are using. You may require an annual commercial license depending on your circumstances. http://www.greensock.com/club/ $150/yr per developer isn't worth it for us as it's only for an about page effect, we wouldn't need it anywhere else on the site.

Comment: Oh, I missed out on that part. Might have to look for another one.

Comment: It's only one animation effect - you wouldn't think it would be that hard to work out where greensock's implementation succeeds especially given all the articles written and the fact the source is in github. It's escaped me though, so I suspect it's some combination of subtleties rather than a silver-bullet.